# How to manually insert page break in JasperReports on basis of certain conditions 

Tags: jasper-reports

I want to check if else condition in subreports for page break like.

I am printing `customername` in pdf report  using jasper template, i need to break the 
page if the customer name is different and the new customer name should be printed in new page. How to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of different possibilities:

### Page Break

1. Add a Page Break
2. Change its PrintWhenExpression

### Report Group

1. Right-click on the report name (in the Report Inspector)
2. Select Add Report Group
3. Provide a Group Name (e.g., UniqueCustomer)
4. Set the Group by value to the `customername` field
5. Click Finish